# Qcircuit: how to insert a new line in a gate?

Tags: line-breaking

here is my question: How can I make this figure?[image: FT quantum computation from Nielsen and Chuang]

I find quite difficult to create two lines in the same gate. For example, all these gates (or mboxes?) are on two lines, but I don't know how to insert a new line!

Any help?
Thank you

Comment: Welcome to TeX-sx! Please add what you have so far: it's always easier to write answers to questions if there is something to build on.

Comment: Have a look at [Qcircuit](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/graphics/qcircuit) and its [tutorial](http://distrib-coffee.ipsl.jussieu.fr/pub/mirrors/ctan/graphics/qcircuit/Qtutorial.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

This is one possibility where `matrix of nodes` from `tikz` is used. Dirac Kets is defined as

```
\newcommand{\ket}[1]{\ensuremath{\left|#1\right\rangle}}
```

and two operators are defined as (to draw the rectangles)

```
\tikzset{
operator/.style  = {draw,fill=white,minimum size=1cm,text width=2cm, align=center},
operator2/.style = {draw,fill=white,minimum height=7em,text width=1cm, align=center},
},
```

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}


\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,calc,positioning}
% Dirac Kets
\newcommand{\ket}[1]{\ensuremath{\left|#1\right\rangle}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick]
% `operator' will only be used by Hadamard (H) gates here.
% `operator2' is for large H gates
\tikzset{
operator/.style  = {draw,fill=white,minimum size=1cm,text width=2cm, align=center},
operator2/.style = {draw,fill=white,minimum height=7em,text width=1cm, align=center},
},

\matrix[row sep=0.4cm, column sep=0.8cm] (circuit) { % 8 columns    % First row.
 \node (q1) {\ket{0}$^{\otimes7}$};  
&\node[operator] (H11) {FT prepare\\ \ket{0_L}};
&\node[operator] (H12) {FT error correct};
&\node[operator] (H13) {FT H};
&\node[operator] (H14) {FT error correct};
&\node[](H15){};  
&\node[operator] (H16) {FT error correct};
&\node[operator] (H17) {FT measure};\\
% Second row.
 \node (q2) {\ket{0}$^{\otimes7}$};  
&\node[operator] (H21) {FT prepare\\\ket{0_L}};
&\node[operator] (H22) {FT error correct};
&
&\node[operator] (H24) {FT error correct};
&\node[](H25){};  
&\node[operator] (H26) {FT error correct};
&\node[operator] (H27) {FT measure};\\
};

\begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
\draw[thick] (q1) -- (H17.west)  (q2) -- (H27.west);
\node[] at ($(q1)!0.35!(H11)$) {/};
\node[] at ($(q2)!0.35!(H21)$) {/};
\node[operator2] at ($(H15)!0.5!(H25)$){FT \\CNOT};  %<-- for large rectangle
%}
\end{pgfonlayer}
    %
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

The gate commands such as `\gate` accept a wide variety of LaTeX as a valid gate label, so you just need to figure out how to typeset whatever label you want for the gate in LaTeX.  In your case the easiest thing to do is probably to use the `\parbox` command to generate a box with multiple lines of text.

I've included the code and output for a simple example below.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\input{Qcircuit}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{c}
\vspace{-.6em}\\
\Qcircuit @R=.2em @C=.5em @!R {
& \gate{\parbox{1.5cm}{\centering FT error\\ correct}} & \qw
}
\vspace{1.2em}\\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Illustration of a gate with a multiline label]